# Why doesn't every scatter point have a click handler on Victory Charts Scatter chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I am working with version 18 of Victory Charts (npm package is victory). I have created a Scatter chart and I'm attempting to pass an onClick event to each point on the scatter plot. However, only a maximum of two points, but usually only one point, receives this onClick handler. The number of points does not matter - only a maximum of two receive the onClick handler.

```
                    <VictoryGroup data={data}>
                        <VictoryScatter
                            size={6}
                            style={{
                                data: {
                                    fill: d => {
                                        if (d.fill) return d.fill
                                        return isSomething(d) ? colors('green') : colors('red')
                                    },
                                    cursor: 'hand',
                                },
                            }}
                            events={[
                                {
                                    target: 'data',
                                    eventHandlers: {
                                        onClick: (e, bubble) => {
                                            DO SOMETHING AMAZING AND GROUDBREAKING
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            ]}
                        />
                        <VictoryVoronoiTooltip />
                    </VictoryGroup>
```

I have tried using the eventKey attribute, to no avail. It shouldn't matter anyway as the documentation states "If no eventKey is specified, events will be attached to all elements of a specified target type" Victory charts is on version 21, but I am trying to avoid the update since they have deprecated the the VoronoiTooltip. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, too future readers. I got this too work. I had to add the `events` attribute to the VictoryGroup component instead of VictoryScatter and specify a `childName` attribute, which I gave as `Object.keys(data)`